# sql server join with group by with selecting number of rows from group

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

there is one table which contains suppose following rows:

```
guid, id, deptName, studentName, Score, Year
guid, 1, IT, ABC, 50, 2019
guid, 2, IT, XYZ, 80, 2018
guid, 1, IT, ABC, 70, 2018
guid, 4, CS, LMN, 60, 2019
```

Now, expected result I want is for every deptName: latest row of above table with order by year in descending order with previous year score of respective student also.(means current row score as current score and its second row score as previous score if it is not available then value will be null)

how to write sql query for this result?

```
guid, id, deptName, studentName, Score, Year, PreviousYearScore
guid, 1, IT, ABC, 50, 2019, 70
guid, 4, CS, LMN, 60, 2019, NULL
```

so, result model will be like:

```
id, deptName, studentName, Score, Year, PreviousYearScore
```

Comment: Hi find my answer

Comment: Hi i just edited the answer ,i used lead function to get the previous year score instead of Lag()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ,Using window function i find the student and his scores based on latest year and i using LEAD() to find the previous year score

```
;WITH CTE (guid, id, deptName, studentName, Score, Year)
AS
(
SELECT 'guid', 1, 'IT', 'ABC', 50, 2019 UNION ALL
SELECT 'guid', 2, 'IT', 'XYZ', 80, 2018 UNION ALL
SELECT 'guid', 1, 'IT', 'ABC', 70, 2018 UNION ALL
SELECT 'guid', 4, 'CS', 'LMN', 60, 2019
)
SELECT [guid],
       id,
       deptName,
       studentName,
       Score,
       [Year],
       PreviousYearScore
FROM
(
SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY deptName ORDER BY [Year] DESC) AS Rnk,
            LEAD(Score,1)OVER(PARTITION BY deptName ORDER BY [Year] DESC) PreviousYearScore     
FROM CTE
)dt 
WHERE Rnk = 1
ORDER BY Id
```

Result

```
guid    id  deptName    studentName Score   Year   PreviousYearScore
------------------------------------------------------------------------
guid    1     IT            ABC      50     2019        70
guid    4     CS            LMN      60     2019        NULL
```